# HTTP Web Request

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I am halfway done with this project. I need to login to my server at work, then submit a form on a different page. How do I keep the login connection alive then post a second form, or url?

```
Dim postData As String = "Username=system&Password=system&Action=Srh-1-1&Go=Login"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("MY SERVER URL"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "MY SERVER URL"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        'logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
```

So, the login works fine. But, again, how do i now post to a different form, or load the entire form + submission details into a url? I need to post data after being logged in and submit the form. The form will return data I will then parse out. Basically, all of this can be done manually but this program will save me time by logging in, submitting, and parsing automatically.

Comment: Do you know what happens after you log in in order to access the next page? Does it create a cookie? The answer to your question depends a lot on the login process. I would recommend using Fiddler to investigate what is being passed back and forth.

Comment: Of course there is a cookie. But what is the point of "keep alive = true" if you cant send a request as soon as the login is complete?

Comment: "of course"? really? i don't think you understand keep alive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection . it just keeps the connection open, so it doesn't have to renegotiate it. if the log in creates a cookie, then pass it back.